# Python change labels attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, label

I want to change labels attr such as id , for , class , etc
I'd tried

```
self.fields['tipo'].attrs['for'] = 'Test'
```

But it's not working , any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
self.fields['tipo'].widget.attrs['class']
```

Comment: That changes the inputs attr not the labels one